# jQuery/JavaScript: Using a JavaScript array in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I'm pretty new to jQuery and I have the following issue:

I have made a JS script that compares user input to a bunch of `<h3>` elements that represent movie titles.

```
userinput = userinput.toLowerCase(); 
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("h3"); //dit wordt de lijst met titels
var i = list.length,
    html, flag = false,
    matches = []; 

while (i--)//here, we loop through the list of <h3>'s
{
    var html = list[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase();
    if (-1 < html.indexOf(userinput))
    {
        flag = true;
        matches.push(list[i]); 
        list[i].className = "matched";
    }
}

if (!flag)//no match 
{if (-1 !== html.indexOf(userinput))
    alert('No match found !');
}
else//match!
{
    for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++)
    {

        $("#overzicht_list").children(":not('')").remove();

  }
}
```

as you can see, I first declare some variables that I'm gonna use. Then, I loop through the list of `<h3>` elements and if one of the elements matches the user input I want to do the following.

All of the elements in my container `overzicht_list` BUT the matched `<h3>` element should be removed. I tried using the following jQuery for this:

```
$("#overzicht_list").children(":not('')").remove();
```

But I really cannot figure out how to refer to the `matches[i]` array within jQuery! I tried `#matches[i]` and stuff like that, but that does not seem to work. Can any of you help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You would need to [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter)

```
$("#overzicht_list").children().filter(function(){
   return $(this).text().indexOf(matches[i]) < -1;
}).remove();
```

Comment: This code doesn't seem to be working yet... can I just add this instead of my $("#overzicht_list").children(":not('')").remove();?           Also, could you perhaps elaborate on what exactly your .filter(function) is checking?

Answer (score -1):

I try to write your script in jQuery, and i try remove useless loop.
I hope my script no change the behavior of your script:

*find `h3` element with `userinout` var inside text and remove it form DOM (during the loop or after), if no one was matched script fire an alert.*

VER.1

```
var userinput = userinput.toLowerCase(), 
    flag = false;

//select and loop all H3 (with jQuery)
$("h3").each(function(){

    //if text inside H3 match with userinput
    if($(this).text().indexOf(userinput)  >= 0){
        //add class matched to the matched element
        $(this).addClass("matched");

        //flat to true
        flag = true;
    }
});

//check flag (if true remove al matched element)
if(flag)$("#overzicht_list .matched").remove();
else alert("No match found!");
```

or, next script is the same, but remove directly the matched element inside first loop:

VER.2

```
var userinput = userinput.toLowerCase(),
    flag = false;
$("h3").each(function(){
    if($(this).text().indexOf(userinput) >= 0){

        //directly remove matched element
        $(this).remove();
        flag = true;
    }
});

//if no one matched alert
if(!flag) alert("No match found!");
```

... right now you not have `matches` variable because it is useless, when you remove elements form DOM, you remove them references inside `matches`.

Comment: I don't think you fully understood my problem ;) What I want to do is check the user input to all the <h3> elements and if there is a match, remove everything within my container EXCEPT for the matches <h3>. Your script does the exact opposite, namely remove nothing but the match.